# How do I return type dynamically using List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I've got some WebApi controller and I want to get data from it. I've got various kinds of DTOs and I want to have a function that handles them all. 
Is there a way to do it?

I want to achieve something like this:

```
  public dynamic GetData(string ControllersName, dynamic DTOType)
        {         
            string Url = Settings.baseURLAddress + ControllersName;
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);

                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<DTOType>));
                var response = (List<DTOType>)serializer.ReadObject(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using generics?

```
public List<T> GetData<T>(string ControllersName, T DTOType)
{         
     string Url = Settings.baseURLAddress + ControllersName;
     var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);

     DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
     var response = (List<T>)serializer.ReadObject(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
     return response;
}
```

Comment: Use IEnumerable<T> to return from Controllers

Comment: Would it be better (and why?)

Answer (score 1):

You could you generics

```
public List<T> GetData<T>(string ControllersName)
{         
     string Url = Settings.baseURLAddress + ControllersName;
     var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);

     DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
     return (List<T>)serializer.ReadObject(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
}
```

**Usage**

```
var myList = GetData<SomeType>(someName);
```

---

**Further Reading**

[Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

> Generics introduce to the .NET Framework the concept of type
>   parameters, which make it possible to design classes and methods that
>   defer the specification of one or more types until the class or method
>   is declared and instantiated by client code.

Comment: This won't compile, ReadObject returns an object which can't be implicitly casted to the List<T> the method returns.

Comment: Alternatively you can use IEnumerable